# Como reemplazar mis alert por sweet alert - formulario html y procesado en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, sweetalert2

de que forma puedo implementar o reemplazar mis alert tradicionales al momento de guardar un registro, por sweet alert.

Mi formulario en html es el siguiente:

```
<h2>Agregar registro</h2>


<form action='procesar.php' method='post'>

Nro. Interno:
<input name="nro_inve" id="nro_inve" type="text">

<br>

Serial:
<input name="serial_inve" id="serial_inve" type="text">
<br>

Marca:
<select name="marca_inve">
      <option value="BRIDGESTONE">BRIDGESTONE</option>
      <option value="MICHELIN">MICHELIN</option>
      <option value="GOODYEAR">GOODYEAR</option>
</select>
<br>

Tamaño:
<input name="dimen_inve" id="serial_inve" type="text">
<br>

Diseño:
<input name="tipo_inve" id="serial_inve" type="text">

<br>

<input type="submit" name="submitcsv" value="GUARDAR"/>
</form>
```

Y luego al presionar e botón GUARDAR el va a procesar.php y si todo esta correcto dependiendo de la condición me muestra el mensaje en un alert.

```
require("conexion.php");
$conexion=conectar();


/* AQUÍ RECIBO LAS VARIABLES*/

$nro_inve=$_POST['nro_inve'];
$serial_inve=$_POST['serial_inve'];
$marca_inve=$_POST['marca_inve'];
$dimen_inve=$_POST['dimen_inve'];
$tipo_inve=$_POST['tipo_inve'];


$sql="insert into inventario(nro_inve,serial_inve,marca_inve,dimen_inve,tipo_inve)
values('$nro_inve','$serial_inve','$marca_inve','$dimen_inve','$tipo_inve')";

/* Y LUEGO ALLI ABAJO ESTAN LOS ALERT DEPENDIENDO DE LA CONDICIÓN ME MUESTRA
UN ALERT POSITIVO O NEGATIVO, ESTOS ALERT QUISIERA CAMBIARLOS POR SWEET ALERT
PARA QUE SE VEAN MÁS GRANDES Y MUCHO MEJOR */

$ok=mysql_query($sql,$conexion);
if ($ok)
    {
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('El registro se realizo correctamente');
        window.location='balance.php';
        </script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Error! intentalo nuevamente')
    window.location='balance.php';</script>";
    }
```

Como puedo hacer para cambiar esos alert por sweet alert para que se puedan ver más grandes y mucho mejor.

Muchísimas gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas descargar la librería para usar el sweetalert a tu proyecto e importarlo en tu pagina... o pon esto:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

y en donde tengas un alert reemplazalo asi :

```
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
        swal('El registro se realizo correctamente');
        window.location='balance.php';
        </script>";
```

y tendras algo asi :

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script> swal('El registro se realizo correctamente');  </script>
```

Comment: Buenas stre_leon aun no me funciona, hice lo que mencionaste y cuando guardo un registro solo se actualiza la pantalla no dice ningun mensaje solo inserta el registro y ya. ya no muestra los alert.

Comment: Cuál de las dos opciones usaste ?... Descargar la librería o poner el link?! Sí fue la segunda considera que debes de tener internet...

Comment: Listo ya me funciono, descargue la libreria y la ajuste a mi codigo, y listo funciona con o sin internet sin problemas. muchas gracias.